# Can't place Frame at the bottom in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I am wondering why the following does not place the bottom frame across the bottom of the root window. My expected outcome is

```
     cyan
     red
black | green
     white
```

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.state('zoomed')
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w-15, h-75))
top = tk.Frame(root, bg='cyan')
top.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
top2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
top2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

right = tk.Frame(root, bg='lightgreen')
right.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

left = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
left.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

bottom = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
bottom.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try  `BOTTOM` before `LEFT` and `RIGHT`

Comment: This gives: cyan red white stacked ontop of each other, without the LEFT RIGHT ones

Comment: LEFT and RIGHT are there but they don't have height. If you set height then you should see them. Or better put normal frame instead LEFT and RIGHT and then put LEFT and RIGHT inside this frame.

Comment: if you add width for white frame in your original version then you see in one line `black | white | green`